# how to looping through dataset and change data c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

im trying to loop through a dataset and where ever there is a 0 i want to change that to a null value or blank so far i have this

```
foreach (DataRow drRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{            
     //loop through cells in that row
      {
        //if the value is 0 change to null or blank
      }
}
```

can any one help me out of this?

Comment: if the task is to replace all zeroes with `NULL` just write SQL UPDATE Statement and exec the script. whats the purpose of loading data into `dataset`? and why are you using c#. IMO SQL scripting is better solution

Answer (score 3):

Sure

```
foreach (DataRow drRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)

    {
        for(int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            int rowValue;

            if (int.TryParse(drRow[i].ToString(), out rowValue))
            {
                if (rowValue == 0)
                {
                    drRow[i] = null;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

I really believed that nobody still works with DataSets :(

Comment: There are still cases in which a DataSet is a valid option.

Comment: the only reason im using dataset is that im trying to connect to a Interbase Database and manipulate the data then showing the new data in charts and grid views. can you suggest a better way of doing this ?

Comment: I am non judging you. It depends on your particular case, for me it's preferable to work with some more cool data layers. You can use Nhibernate with standard dialect, but it could be overkill for your case. DataSets have out of date approach to work with data.

Comment: There are scenarios in which you just want to pass an abitrary table from module A to module B. Using a dataset allows you to modify the table without harming all your other code. If you have a static typed object and you want to add a property you will have to recompile everything which is not always possible.

Comment: If you need module A to pass to module B some data without static typing why not to use dynamic?

Comment: I'm not sure if anyone here use _batch_ (allows you to execute multiple SQL statement as one). I think that is one example when to use DataSet.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help:

```
foreach (DataRow rows in table.Rows)
{
    object value = null;
    var cells = rows.ItemArray;
    for (int i = 0; i < cells.Length; i++)
    {
        value = cells[i];
        if (value != null && value.GetType() == typeof(int))
        {
            if ((int)value == 0)
            {
                cells[i] = null;
            }
        }
    }
    rows.ItemArray = cells;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
.....
.....

    DataRowCollection drColl = dt.Rows;
                for(int j=0; j<drColl.Count;j++) 
                {
                    DataRow drRow = drColl[j];
                    object[] itemArr = null;
                    itemArr = drRow.ItemArray;
                    //loop through cells in that row       
                    for(int i=0; i<itemArr.Length; i++)
                    {         
                        //if the value is 0 change to null or blank 
                        if (itemArr[i].ToString() == "0")
                            drRow[i] = "";
                    } 
                }
```